# Expression evaluation is async frame is not supported

Tags: flutter, dart

I having the following error message when I try to use Chrome web browser.

\> ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'ServicesBinding': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 14..

***ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'ui.PlatformDispatcher.instance': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 14..***

***> ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'message': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 14.***

I think it has to do with the "completer.complete(reply);" code in the "bining.dart" file.

[image]

I can't seem to get a solution for it. I'm trying to build a dashboard UI and I'm using chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

'`Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported`' seems to be a bigger issue that is not limited to ChromeProxyService. See the post

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/11913

for the circumstances that trigger it.

So my suggestion is to ignore that line where the execution stops, and look for a bug elsewhere in the calling function.